# Enumerating the video capture devices with DirectShow works well in console but does not work with Unity (2018.2.12)

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-capture, directshow, directshow.net

I use Unity 2018.2.12 and [DirectShow.Net](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/)

I created simple code that enumerates video capture devices. It founds devices but it cannot obtain their FriendlyName property under being running as Unity script.

```
using DirectShowLib;
using UnityEngine;

namespace DirectShow.Net_Tests {
    public class CodeForUnity : MonoBehaviour {

        void Start() {
            foreach (var device in DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice))
            {
                Debug.Log(
                    $"Device Name:\t{device.Name}\n" +
                    $"\tDevice FriendlyName (Property):\t{device.GetPropBagValue("FriendlyName")}\n" +
                    $"\tDevice Class GUID:\t{device.ClassID}\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The same code can obtain FriendlyName property being running as console application.

```
using System;
using DirectShowLib;

namespace DirectShow.Net_Tests {
    static class Program {

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            foreach (var device in DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Device Name:\t{device.Name}\n" +
                    $"\tDevice FriendlyName (Property):\t{device.GetPropBagValue("FriendlyName")}\n" +
                    $"\tDevice Class GUID:\t{device.ClassID}\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why does not it work in Unity?

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with Debug.Log

Comment: @VuVirt This function outputs a string to the console in Unity. What could be the problem?

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/757659/console-not-outputting-from-debuglog.html